# Using Bezier Paths

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit

i defined this to convert degrees to radians

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees) ((3.14159 * degrees)/180)
```

then i added this code snippet to my `viewDidLoad`. I am trying to create an arc here.

```
UIBezierPath *innerPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(150, 150) radius:75 startAngle:0 endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(135) clockwise:YES];
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    innerPath.lineWidth = 5;
    [innerPath fill];
    [innerPath stroke];
```

However the arc does not appear when I run my app in the simulator. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Drawing in `viewDidLoad` has no effect...there is no drawing context at this point.  As rob says, you must draw in `drawRect:`

Answer (score 1):

First, use `M_PI` instead of 3.14159.

Second, you need to do your drawing in a view's `drawRect:` method.  Read about the [UIKit drawing model](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/DrawingModel.html) for more details.